# List and change user credentials in svn

Tags: svn

I have two remote svn platforms who was not configurated by me, where I want to change the password of a user, but in each svn/config in both authz and passwd there are no users. Seems that in each svn there is different list of users.

So where can I find or display/change user accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you or your colleagues built the server manually, you should check its config to find out where `htpasswd` file is located. See [SVNBook | Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.html) for more information.

If you use VisualSVN Server, the credentials are either fully controlled by your Active Directory domain or are stored in C:\Repositories\htpasswd file. It depends on whether you enable AD integration in server settings.

Comment: I forgot to say that this is a virtual private server. I have already search for **bold**htpassd**bold** but no success. I only have two apache installations in this server, one belongs to another service and there is other in a folder named migration but in httpd.conf there is no reference to any of those svn's. =/ Also doesnt seem that an AD is being used, this is a linux system.

Comment: Also there is a hidden subversion folder but there is nothing there, in: **bold**/home/qwe/.subversion/**bold**

Comment: htpasswd is an hidden file at svn root folder, just to complete the answer.